# How to use another device camera as input for NAO robot

Tags: python, image, nao-robot

Is it possible to use as camera input another device (like a tablet camera) instead of the robot’s camera? If possible, how should I do that using Python or through libraries using command line?

Comment: Yes it is, I will edit the question to make it more clear, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In our team, we've made a custom build to adress the problem of learning faces and recognize from files instead of standard robot camera.

You can clone our public repo:

git clone http://protolab.aldebaran.com:9000/protolab/facedetection_custom.git

You'll find compiled library binary for various classic version, pick the right one...

Don't hesitate to ask question if something's unclear...

Comment: Yes I am aware of the library, I tried it for face detection and it is very useful. But is it not possible to do it directly through changing the camera input? I need it for height estimation as well, and height estimation uses ALPeoplePerception module instead. Or is there another way to estimate the height using an image?

Comment: If you know the size of the face and it's position on the screen and angles of the joint ("tf") you can easilly compute the height of the human.